# How would I create, for Kivy, a 'for loop' in order to create buttons which have text that correspond to each element in the 'for loop'?

Tags: python, for-loop, button, kivy

I am creating a game in Kivy. I have the code that generates a list of both random letters, and letters that make up a specific word. I want to use a 'for loop' or possibly any other way to create buttons for every letter in this list, bearing in mind that the list of letters changes with every level of the game.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: DJGrandpaJ's right. If you want help - show us your code